# How to put http response into a Set

Tags: java, rest, http, set, response

How can i put http response into a set(Collection Set) of Employee type.

I am getting data as HTTP response but i am have to put it inside a set(Collection Set) of Employee type

```java
public Set<Employee> getAllEmployees() throws ServiceException {
    setOtherAppDetails();
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside newly created DNG controller method");
        String postUrl = "http://localhost:8081/otherApp/empserv/list/dngEmployees";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("responseBody =" +EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        // employees.add((Employee)response); wants to do something like this but its not working, sorry if it seems silly 
    }  catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }       
    return employees;
}
```

The response should be kept in Set

Comment: What is the format of the response you get? How does it look like?

Comment: "id":"5","text":null,"category":"Employees"  -- It comes like this contains more data

Comment: It might be [JSON](https://www.json.org/).What is the value of Content-Type header you get in HttpResponse?

Comment: yes it is of json type

Comment: You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library Jackson to parse a json as Set.

If you use Maven first import the [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9.2)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can parse the http response as following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Set<Employee> myObjects = mapper.readValue(EntityUtils.toString(entity), new TypeReference<Set<Employee>>(){});
```

The object Employee need to be the exact rappresentation of the response

More examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)